# want to replace a number in many files

Tags: bash, shell, perl, csh

I have x file which has file names (a.txt,b.txt,c.txt....j.txt) and y file which has (1,2,3,4,....).I want to replace a constant number (which is same throught out each file) with corresponding number like in a.txt=1,b.txt=2,c.txt=3....... 
I have tried with following code

```
open my $handle, '<', "y";
@words = <$handle>;
close($handle);

open(my $fh,"x") or die "Couldn't open file file.txt, $!";
while ( $count = <$fh>) {

  print @words ;
  print $count;
  system("  sed -i 's/129/$words[$i]/g' '$count' ") ;

  $i++;
}
close ($fh);
```

this is not replacing anything in file.
Edit: a.txt is file name looks like 
hey im human.
129
and hey im human is common to all b.txt,c.txt till j.txt.and 129 is constant number i want to replace it by 1,2,3... in coresponding file(in a.txt 1 should be there, in b.txt 2 should be there.)
Please share your concerns.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I have edited your code to make the formatting more consistent. You're welcome, of course, but please consider doing it yourself in the future. Careful indentation is an important tool for making your code easier to understand. If you're asking a large group of strangers to read and understand your code, it's surely polite to put some effort into making that as easy as possible for them.

Comment: Do you get any errors or output? Because on the first line, you don't actually check whether `y` opens correctly. But it's also not clear if there are any files called `$count` (which looks like it's a string, which is pretty bad style) for `sed` to work on... for that matter, why are you even using `sed` when you can do the same thing within perl?

Comment: Show the output of the script.

Comment: actually i have printed contents of y file by doing print @words. its working fine ,and $count has the content of x file.Im ok with perl also ,i just tried sed . @ Sobrique

Comment: unterminated `s' command: This is the error i got . And there is problem with $count even because its showing this errorUse of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at line 21,<$fh> @123

Answer (score 0):

It's really not very clear what you're trying to achieve. But here are three tips which might make it easier for you track down your problem.

1. Always add `use strict` and `use warnings` to your code. And fix the problems that they will show you.
2. When reading data from a file, it will still have newlines at the end of each record. Use `chomp()` to remove those.
3. Calling `sed` from a Perl program is a strange choice. There's nothing that `sed` can do that you can't do easier using Perl.

Comment: actually i have added use stricts and all before ,i have just attached main part of code.And yes im having error on sed line . I can add perl also in that

Comment: @Anthonyj: I'm pretty sure that my point 2 will address your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried with csh foreach and its working fine now .

Comment: @Anthonyj - Or you could have just used `chomp()` as I suggested.